# Why is SERVER_NAME variable returning incorrect value in tomcat 8 URL Rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, tomcat8

I am migrating URL rewrite functionality from apache mod_rewrite to Tomcat 8's RewriteValve. I have apache web servers running behind load balancer. There are some URLs getting rewritten based on the domain name.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^xyz.com
RewriteRule /pattern$ /substitution [L]
```

In Apache's mod_rewrite, the SERVER_NAME variable was working fine. However in tomcat 8 the variable is returning the IP address of the machine instead of the server name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Variables section in [Tomcat's SSI document](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssi-howto.html)

> SERVER_NAME   The server's hostname or IP address.
>
> HTTP_HOST The web site that the client requested.

Using HTTP_HOST variable in RewriteRules fixed my problem.